# Do I need to deploy function in gcloud in order to have OCR?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

This GCloud Tutorial has a "[Deploying the function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#deploying_the_functions)", such as

```
gcloud functions deploy ocr-extract --trigger-bucket YOUR_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME --entry-point
```

But at [Quickstart: Using Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) does not mention it at all, all it needs is

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
```

then a few lines of code will work.

So I'm confused, do I need the "deploy" in order to have OCR, in other words what do/don't I get from "deploy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Cloud Function (CF) is easy to understand, this answers specifically my own question,  what does the "Deploy" actually do:

1. to have the code work for you, they must be deployed/uploaded to the GC. For people like me never done GCF this is new. My understanding was all I need to supply is credentials and satisfy the whatever server/backend (sorry, cloud) settings when my **local** app calls the remote Web API. That's where I stucked. The key I missed is the sample app itself is a server/backend event-handler trigger **functions**, and therefore Google requires them to be "deployed" just like when we deploy something during a staging or production release in a traditional corporate environment. So it's a real deploy. If you still don't get it, go to your GC admin page, menu, Cloud Function, "Overview" tab, you will see them. Hence goes to next
2. The 3 GC deploy command used in the [Deploying Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#deploying_the_functions) have `ocr-extract ocr-save ocr-translate`, they are not switches, they are function **names** that you can name them anything. Now, still in the Admin page, click on any of 3, "Source". Bang, they are there, deployed (uploaded).

Google, as this is a tutorial no one has digged into command reference book yet, I recommend adding a piece of note telling readers those 3 `ocr-*` can be anything you want to name.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
```

is an example of installing the Google Cloud Client Library for Node.js in your development environment, in this case, Cloud Storage API. This example is part of [Setting Up a Node.js Development Environment](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/setup) tutorial.

Once you have coded, tested and set all the configurations for the app as described in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#functions_ocr_configure-nodejs) the next step would be the deployment, in this example a Cloud Function:

```
gcloud functions deploy ocr-extract --trigger-bucket YOUR_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME --entry-point
```

So, note that this commands are two different steps to run OCR with Cloud Functions, Cloud Storage and other Cloud Platform components in the tutorial example using Node.js environment.

Comment: `npm install ...` is easy to understand to have all libraries/frameworks downloaded to my local box for development. But `deploy` takes only my imageBucket in as param, so it's like **enabling** the ocr feature of this bucket, means as long as an app utilizing this bucket, it will be allowed to use the ocr feature of it. Right?

Comment: `deploy`  deploys your Cloud Function. During deployment you need to specify the bucket that will be used as the trigger for executing the first Cloud Function because Cloud Storage is the Event Trigger for the CF. The OCR is not a unified "feature", but a functionality that can be achieved by using multiple GCP products, namely: Cloud Functions, Cloud Storage, Vision API, Translation API, Pub/Sub. You will need 1 bucket for uploading images that will undergo the OCR process and another bucket to store the translation results. If this did not help clear confusion, please ask another question.